# Creating buttons that display buttons

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to make an online questionnaire that will only show the next question after answering the current question. I am very new at this and trying to learn as I go. How do I make the 2nd set of buttons appear only when you answer yes to question 1?

```html
<html>
Question 1
<p>

<button onclick="myFunction1()">Yes</button>
<script>
function myFunction1() {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Yes on question 1, display question 2";document.getElementById("demo").style.color = "black";}

</script>

<button onclick="myFunction2()">No</button>





<script>
function myFunction2() { document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML ="No on question 1 negative answer to question 1 display negative response";document.getElementById("demo").style.color = "red";}
</script>
</html>
<p id="demo"></p>


</script>

</p></p></p>

</html>

<head>
    <script>
        function showImg() {
            document.getElementById("map_img").style.display = "";
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
   <button onclick="myFunction3()">Yes</button> 




<script>
function myFunction3() {  document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = "Yes to question 2";}</script>
</html>


<button onclick="myFunction4()">No</button> 
<script>
function myFunction4() {
    document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = "No to question 2";}
</script>


</body>

<p id="demo2"></p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion, you have to put your second, third and ... questions into div's tags with style="display:none"

When the users click on the Yes button, you can easily change the display to block and show the next question.

Another thing is that your html is not formatted well.

Here is an example of html.

```
<html>
   <head>
   </head>
   <body>
     <div>Your first question</div>
     <div style="display:none" id="question2">Your second question</div>

     <script>
       You can put all your functions here
     </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

I did a very simple example for you, you can check on the following link:

https://jsfiddle.net/L7gp4c5g/

Hope to help you!

Comment: This looks perfect for what I need. Thanks so much

Comment: Please see also the @doua-beri answer. He used an amazing JavaScript syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Use css `display: none;` to hide the second question, then when the user clicks the yes button, you change it to `display:block;`
Here is an example: https://jsfiddle.net/mrpbtbgy/2/

```
document.querySelector("#q1Btn").addEventListener("click",()=>{
    document.querySelector("#question2").style.display="block";
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the what you want to hide in a div hidden:

```
<div id="question2" style="visibility: hidden">
    <button onclick="onClick(2)">Yes</button> 
    <button onclick="onClick(2)">no</button> 
</div>
```

Use javascript to programmatically hide or show next div:

```
<script>
    function onClick(button) {
        document.getElementById('question' + (button + 1)).style.visibility = "visible"
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

As other I would have said : 
If you want to get the results at the end of all the questions. (if user leave, you won't get nothing.)

A solution would be to put each question in hidden divs, on the same page, displaying them after each validation. This way you won't need to put and remove content. Example:

```js
function showquestion(number){
$("#question"+number).removeClass("hidden"); // Show the next question
$("#question"+(number-1)).addClass("hidden"); // Hide the current question
}
```

```css
.hidden{display:none;
visibility : hidden;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="question1" class=""> Mauvaise réponse</div>
<div id="question1" class=""> Question 1 <button type="button" onclick="showquestion(0)">yes</button><button type="button" onclick="showquestion(2)">No</button></div>
<div id="question2" class="hidden"> Question 2 <button type="button" onclick="showquestion(0)">yes</button><button type="button" onclick="showquestion(3)">no</button></div>
<div id="question3" class="hidden"> Question 3 <button type="button" onclick="showquestion(0)">yes</button><button type="button" onclick="showquestion(4)">no</button></div>
```

But we forgot the "yes / no" part, nor talk about the visibility of the question solution inside the source code.

The correct way of doing this would be an ajax call on each question validation : The user send the response to a php script, this script validate the response, or not, then send the content that will be inserted on the user page.
It's the only way for the user don't cheat, and it allow you to save his response on each step (if you save something).